# External Memory(ies) Usage for Max Speed

Tags: arm

I haven't used external memory OR ARM core micros before; all of the micros I've used have had internal FLASH and separate data/program address spaces. So forgive me if these questions are very basic, but I could use a "sanity check" to make sure I'm not missing something important:

I have an existing program that when compiled for one micro has the following memory table (IAR for Cortex M3):
   40 620 bytes of readonly  code memory
    1 215 bytes of readonly  data memory
  126 900 bytes of readwrite data memory

I am moving to a micro that has NO internal FLASH and 128kB of internal SRAM, as it has a very high processor speed that I need. My plan is to use external NOR FLASH (let's say 512kB for the sake of argument) and at least one DDR2 external RAM (again, assume 512kB+ for sake of argument).

I'd like to copy the contents of the external FLASH into internal SRAM at boot-up (a bootloader is provided in a separate internal FLASH space), and execute code out of SRAM.  What I'm still not clear on is if the 128kB of internal SRAM is sufficient to allow for this. Can I simply use the DDR2 external RAM to house all "data", and execute the program code out of SRAM? Is there a speed compromise this way? Speed is my #1 priority in this application. Is there a way to do this that will result in quicker execution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the arm is connected to those memories (flash, sram, dram) then you would be able to use them however you like.  run what you can from sram have other stuff in dram.  dram in general is much slower than sram, but you might have a cache to help and other factors that may make one or the other memory worse/better.  if using gnu tools you can certainly craft a linker script and bootloader that takes the various segments .text, .data, .rodata, etc and sets them up wherever you want them (sram, dram, specific places in each, etc), and then let the arm go have at it...For IAR I dont know much about that but no doubt they have some mechanism as well for doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks again, dwelch. My primary concern was I am a bit confused about the memory sizes. If my current program has the following memory map: 40 620 bytes of readonly code memory 1 215 bytes of readonly data memory 126 900 bytes of readwrite data memory, it's not clear to me that I can copy the code into internal SRAM AND have enough SRAM with 128kB to house the data. I'm confused as to where the R/W data can be located. If it's in an external DDR2, am I going to pay a speed price? I know executing code out of external RAM takes about 10x longer than internal FLASH.

Comment: I assume some of that code is specific to that chip so that will change with the new chip?  Other than that I would assume the sizes will be in the ball park, there may be some places where a local load/store, etc would work but now the code may be further apart requiring an additional word, making it a little larger.  No reason why you cant play with toolchain settings now and try to build the existing code for a different memory map, right?  see how large the code as is turns out.

Comment: You're right, but as you discussed in my other post, I suspect that the overall codesize in going from the Cortex M3 to the Cortex A5 will be pretty similar when using the same compiler. I understand there may be some differences due to the libraries.

Comment: well flash read times on cortex-ms are not necessarily fast, so I wouldnt simply assume that external ram is slower, depends on the processor and its busses.  if you dont already know the answer, or a rough estimate of what the times are you may simply have to wait for hardware and benchmark it.

Comment: I would hope the libraries for the peripherals are not a huge size change, but you never know until you look or try.  You should start now trying to build for this other platform and see how much bigger or smaller things get.

Comment: I have the demo board for the Atmel SAMA5D31 I plan to use. Its just that the HW engineer picked this micro before I started on the project and I want to make sure it will work at all before we go too far.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34858/discussion-between-nobby-and-dwelch)